# Law of attraction

Tags: allah, shirk

I've read somewhere that LOA is haram but I was so happy after ages as if I wanted to live but today I searched and searched and finally came to know that it's haram. Idk what to do. After 1,2 weeks I selfharmed again, my mind was bursting, I hate myself AGAIN!
  also I saw somewhere infact at many videos that it is haram as Allah says *seek everything from me, and as a Muslim we must ask everythingg from Him, He is our creator* but LOA says that we should already believe that something is ours and have immense believe
I'm so confused. It's like on one hand ik that it's haram but still I want it to be halal but how can it be halal when LOA tells us that WE CAN HAVE ANYTHING IN THIS WORLD, ANYTHING but on the other hand, Allah says that a leaf can't even move without His will also there are 3 steps to manifest something according to LOA, scripting, visualization and believing as if something is already yours
So i order to have something example if I don't like my face structure so I'll use LOA as *I have V- shaped face structure* and I'll repeat it again and again. But here comes the problem. If I'll keep in mind that I'm asking from Allah and it's dua, then my mind would be in 2 ways that maybe Allah will do because it's good for me or maybe HE won't do. I wouldn't be able to imagine it as it's already mine as it is told to do in LOA. Please I'm sorry if I'm disturbing you but please reply. I've read many articles about islam and LOA, and it says that LOA is just like a dua. And dua is made  for unseen means but in LOA it says that by practicing LOA *WE CAN HAVE ANYTHING* that means, nothing is unseen according to LOA. So what should we do? While scripting, manifesting, I should keep in mind that I can achieve anything or what? Im so confused. Because if we see this from Islamic point of view, it's Allah who can do anything, anything but in LOA, it's our mind which can do anything. And how can I manifest as *I have this face , I am becoming beautiful or I am getting back to the person I loved* when I guess even plastic surgery is haram because maybe (i don't clearly know about that) changing your appearance is haram in Islam.
Moreover when I'll accept that my mind is so powerful that I can attract anything, and I'll have belief in that, then what would be a need to make dua when I'll already know that I can have this thing from LOA. And why didn't Allah tell us about LOA, but instead HE told us to say dua. And wouldn't it be a shirk when I'll trust more on my mind powers , like I'll be knowing that my mind is so powerful that I/it can do anything, I can have anything I want, ( as if I'm worshipping myself/my mind). If I'll have this believe then what would be the need to kneel infront of Allah (I'm not saying I'll do it, ofcourse Allah is our creator and no power is bigger than HIM, HE is the one) but see, here a person gets confused that what should you do, to believe in yourself or Allah. If I'll believe that Allah has granted me this power then still I'll be doubtful that maybe Allah will grant me what I'm asking for or not, while LOA says to have believe and act as if already something is yours  Please I'll be very thankful to you if you reply. I'm at that point of my life where I was few weeks back. Please reply

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question but it is best to use your discretion always in anything. Law of attraction is believed to be a natural phenomon of the universe.  If you want scientific basis of it you can read the book "the field". Human beings are always continueing to learn the nature of reality but what is the actual truth and to which extent we can influence our external reality is only known to Allah. I think Law of attraction will work naturally in your life on autopilot even if you try not to use it. If you remember your childhood how uou have *attracted* certain events or people in your life.
In  every new discovery or ideology there will be division of outlook when it comes to islamic doctarine.  In my views the understaning of such phenmon has to address in totality to come to a full verduct if its shirk or not.
I encourage you not to think of anything as a guarentee of anything but an experiment that can you can do successfully or not. Not even dua to Allah is granted to be accepted. This life is meant for growth and is not created to be perfect.
Allah has said he has power over all things and a leaf doesnt fall by his command. Allah has allowed some free will to human being. Only by his permission everything functions in this world.
As muslims we can modify few practices to always include Allah in every step of the way when we are benefiting from Loa techniques.  Always include Allah in scripting and affirmations. Using your subconcious mind should be ok. Sometimes duas are much more powerful than any loa techniques and is a direct converstation with Allah. Never stop making duas infact if Loa takes you away from duas or Allah it is not worth it. It should mean to incease in tawakul. This is my viewpiont and I am devout muslim who has read about loa as well. Allah knows best.